# Find injective and discontinuous function at $[a,b]$ for which $f([a,b]) = [f(a),f(b)]$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

Find injective and discontinuous  function at $[a,b]$ for which $f([a,b]) = [f(a),f(b)]$

I proved that if function $f [a,b]\to R$ is continuous and non-decreasing then $f([a,b]) = [f(a),f(b)]$ but don't know how to use or even need to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choose any strictly increasing continuous function $g:[a, b] \to \Bbb R$, and two distinct points $c, d \in (a, b)$. Then define $f:[a, b] \to \Bbb R$ as
$$
 f(x) = \begin{cases}
g(d) & \text{ if } x = c \\
g(c) & \text{ if } x = d \\
g(x) & \text{ if } x \ne c,d \, .
\end{cases}
$$
$f$ is injective, with $f([a,b])=g([a,b]) = [g(a),g(b)]= [f(a),f(b)]$, and $f$ is discontinuous at $x=c$ and $x=d$.

A concrete example is  $f:[0, 1] \to \Bbb R$ defined as
$$
 f(x) = \begin{cases}
2/3 & \text{ if } x = 1/3 \\
1/3 & \text{ if } x = 2/3 \\
x & \text{ otherwise.} \
\end{cases}
$$

Another example is  $f:[0, 1] \to \Bbb R$ defined as
$$
 f(x) = \begin{cases}
x & \text{ if } x \in \Bbb Q \\
1-x & \text{ if } x \notin \Bbb Q
\end{cases}
$$
which maps $[0, 1]$ injectively onto itself, and is continuous only at $x=1/2$.